# How to know if two words are the same base?

Tags: javascript, nlp, translation, multilingual, grammar

I want to make an app where a user inputs some word, and then that word is detected and highlighted on the page. The difficult part is that I want all forms of the word to be detected. This would ultimately be for translation purposes.

So if the user enters `eat` I want to have that match with `eat`, `eats`, `eating`, and `ate`.

Ideally this supports multiple languages as well.

Is there a library for this, preferably in JavaScript? So far I've found [this decade old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856347/how-to-know-if-two-words-have-the-same-base) and stuff like the Porter Stemming algorithm, but haven't come across a good, modern solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be looking for a stemming algorithm, in particular the implementation for Javascript.

Here are a couple JS libraries that could get you started:

- Porter stemming algorithm [GitHub repo](https://github.com/words/stemmer)
- Lancaster stemming algorithm (tends to be more aggressive) [GitHub repo](https://github.com/words/lancaster-stemmer)

Not sure if either of them support multiple languages though.

Also, I'd suggest reading some material on the differences to understand which one would suit your use-case better. You could start off with [this article on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/porter-vs-lancaster-stemming-algorithms) and this post [What are the major differences and benefits of Porter and Lancaster Stemming algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554052/what-are-the-major-differences-and-benefits-of-porter-and-lancaster-stemming-alg)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a way to lemmatize the words and use lemma to compare. Here is a good working example that you can follow — ["How to do stemming and lemmatization?"](https://observablehq.com/@winkjs/how-to-do-stemming-and-lemmatization)